# Jenkins continue pipeline on failed stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins setup with a bunch of pipelines.
I wrote a new pipeline which can start all pipelines at once.
I would like to build other stages, even if one of them fails.

The script currently looks like this

```
stage 'CentOS6'
build 'centos6.testing'

stage 'CentOS7'
build 'centos7.testing'

stage 'Debian7'
build 'debian7-x64.testing'

stage 'Debian8'
build 'debian8-x64.testing'
```

The build scripts itself contain the node they should run on.

How can the script continue with the following stages even if one of them fails.

Cheers

Comment: Can't you use try-catch? Similar to this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896729/jenkins-continuous-delivery-pipeline-skip-stage-based-on-input/40907739#40907739

Comment: yes I could, but this would also mark unsuccessfull builds as successfull

Comment: Should they be run in parallell or in a sequence?

Comment: they should run in parallel

Comment: try-catch will work nicely as @MaTePe says. If you want to mark the stages as failed, then have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852310/show-a-jenkins-pipeline-stage-as-failed-without-failing-the-whole-job/42147678#42147678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `parallel` step, this should work as you expect by default, as the `failFast` option, which aborts the job if any of the parallel branches fail, defaults to `false`.

For example:

```groovy
parallel(
    centos6: { build 'centos6.testing' },
    centos7: { build 'centos7.testing' },
    debian7: { build 'debian7-x64.testing' },
    debian8: { build 'debian8-x64.testing' }
)
```

Comment: And how to make job fail as soon as one of the parallel builds fails?

Comment: @azizbekian Add a `failFast: true` branch to the `parallel` block.

Comment: Thanks! Will try that! Will you please also see my [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588457/connectedandroidtest-on-multiple-emulators) question, I hope you can help there too, because it's more or less concerned to the same topic.

Answer (score 5):

If they should be run in a sequence you can do something like this:

```
def buildResult= 'success'
try{
  build 'centos6.testing'
}catch(e){
   buildResult = 'failure'
}
currentBuild.result = buildResult
```

If they should be run in parallell you just run them: 
https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
    'Task' : {
        build( job : "DemoJob-2", wait: false )
        build( job : "DemoJob-3", wait: false )
    }
```