# connectedAndroidTest on multiple emulators

Tags: android, jenkins, android-instrumentation

**Background**

I want to run my Android Instrumented tests on Jenkins on different emulators. Say I have 100 tests and 4 emulators, I want to run 25 tests on each.

I perform `./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest` in Jenkins Pipeline's parallel for 4 emulators

```
stage('Instrumented Tests') {
    parallel(
            emu1: {
                 runInstrumentedTestOnEmu(...)
            },
            emu2: {
                 runInstrumentedTestOnEmu(...)
            }
            ...
    )
}
```

`connectedDebugAndroidTest` will spawn other commands in order to setup the environment for running instrumented tests.

```
...
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebugAndroidTest
:app:processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugAndroidTest
:app:validateSigningDebugAndroidTest
:app:packageDebugAndroidTest
:app:assembleDebugAndroidTest
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
```

And when environment is ready then it performes `:app:connectedDebugAndroidTest` which will start running tests on emulator.

I do not want to run these procedure for all my parallel calls (in this case it would be 4 of them), because obviously I'm doing the exact same job multiple times. Theoretically, the best option would be to perform setup before `parallel` and when everything is ready for running tests, then go into `parallel` step and start tests on each emulator.

**Question**

Is it possible to perform all the pre-setup steps of `connectedDebugAndroidTest` without performing itself?

Additionally, if I run `connectedDebugAndroidTest` parallel on 4 emulators the build crashes, because gradle tries to read a file from `intermediate` directory, when other parallel build has already removed that file, which results in crash.

You can view [this test project in github](https://github.com/azizbekian/AndroidJenkinsPipeline) with setup mentioned above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to perform all the pre-setup steps of connectedDebugAndroidTest without performing itself?

Yes, you can run `assembleDebugAndroidTest`, which as your build log shows, is the last prerequisite to running the device tests.  Running that will build both the app and test APKs.

Though AFAIK, there isn't a way of sharding your tests across multiple emulators when using Gradle — you would have to install both of the APKs onto each emulator and use `adb shell am instrument` with the `numShards` and `shardIndex` options.